# How to mock or stub an external request, not necessarily an http one?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I want to mock or stub an external request. It’s not a simple HTTP request and there’s no direct access to an underlying library, nor information of how it’s implemented under the hood, therefore it should be treated as some external request that can be http, file, database. A simplified code is as follows:

```
def my_external_call
  Lib1::get_some_data()
end
```

I know what my_external_call() can return. How do I mock or stub it?

Comment: Is `my_external_call` a method that is defined on a class, or is it just on the top level? If it was defined on a class, you'd just say `expect(my_class).to receive(:my_external_call).and_return(some_stubbed_result)`

Comment: @maxpleaner in a class or module. And see my comments below please

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
describe "method that uses external service" do
  before do 
    allow(Lib1).to_receive(:get_some_data).and_return(
      { example: "response" }      # or whatever is returned from the external service
    )
  end

  it "works" do
    # your test for the method that triggers the external call
  end
end
```

Comment: ok, but what that will actually test? It won't test a response itselt, its content, but only *presence* of `get_some_data()` in `Lib1`? If so, is there a way to make it more useful?

Comment: Or first of all, will that test make an *actual* external request or not? If an actual request, in what sense is it mocking? How is it better than simply calling `my_external_call()`?

Comment: This example will not test the response of the `Lib1.get_some_data` which IMHO would make any sense at all. You do not want to test methods that return stubbed data because then you would not test the method itself but only your stubbed data. With a test like this, you can test any other method that depends on `Lib1.get_some_data`. It basically tests that the depending method works if `Lib1.get_some_data` returned an expected response. When you want to test the `Lib1.get_some_data` method itself then you cannot stub that method but need to stub more low-level methods within that library.

Comment: When using `allow(object).to_receive(:method_name).and_return(response)` the original implementation of that method will not be called anymore. Therefore the external call within that method will not happen. I would not run external calls in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please read this very famous article from Martin Fowler: [Mocks aren't Stubs](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) so you get a nice understanding of mocks and stubs.